# c++: passing arrays by reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am trying to define a function prototype which takes an array of `char` of different lengths.  I understand that I must pass the array by reference to avoid the array decaying to a pointer to its first element.  So I've been working on this simple example to get my understanding correct.

```
 #include <stdio.h> // size_t

 //template to accept different length arrays
 template<size_t len>
 //pass array of char's by reference
 void func(const char (&str)[len])
 {
     //check to see if the array was passed correctly
     printf(str);
     printf("\n");
     //check to see if the length of the array is known
     printf("len: %lu",len);
 }
 int main(){
     //create a test array of chars
     const char str[] = "test12345";
     //pass by reference
     func(&str);
     return 0;
 }
```

This gives me the compiler errors:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:19:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘func(const char (*)[10])’
     func(&str);
              ^
main.cpp:6:6: note: candidate: template<long unsigned int len> void func(const char (&)[len])
 void func(const char (&str)[len])
      ^~~~
main.cpp:6:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:19:14: note:   mismatched types ‘const char [len]’ and ‘const char (*)[10]’
     func(&str);
```

I thought that the function signature `func(const char (&str)[len])` indicates a pointer to a `char` array of length `len`, which is what I am passing by `func(&str)`.

I tried `func(str)`, which I would expect to be wrong, since I am passing the value str, instead of its reference.  However, this actually works and I dont understand why.

What is going on here?
What does it actually mean to pass by reference?

Comment: I don't understand.  Why not use `std::vector`?  It's easier to pass (you can simply pass by reference) and it has a `size` method.

Comment: `func(*str);` is calling `func(char)` (which there is none, including deducible). The call `func(str)` is passing by reference, not value, because that's how the argument is deduced.

Comment: It looks like you are showing us an error from a different source in which you do `&str` in main.

Comment: I don't quite follow why you are surprised that `func(str)` is the correct way to call the function. If it was an `int i;` instead of a `char[]` and the function took the `int` by reference as `int&`, would you be surprised that `func(i)` is the correct way to call the function? What seems different here to you? Why do you think that `const char (&str)[len]` is a pointer? As you said at the beginning it is a reference, not a pointer.

Comment: Completely unrelated, sending strings as the format string argument to `printf` solo is a *really* bad idea. Use `puts` or at least `printf("%s", str)`, and ideally, just `std::cout << str;`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews,  I'm not using std::vector because I'm modifying code in an existing library.  I want to minimize the change and keep compatibility.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR,  Yes you are right.  I fixed it in the post

Comment: @user17732522
`const char (&str)[len]` seemed like a pointer to me because of the `&` operator.
`&str` is the address of `str`.  So it seems that `(&str)` is a pointer parameter.

Comment: @Mr.Weathers My impression is that you are not aware of what a _reference_ in C++ is. `&` in a type has nothing to do with pointers. It indicates a reference. See [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in).

Comment: @Mr.Weathers `&` in a formal parameter declaration is *never* a pointer-to indicator; it means reference in that context *always*. Ex: `void foo(Type &arg);` You're mistakenly seeing `&` as you would in its functional context where it means address-of, which is a different beast entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is declared correctly, but you are not passing the array to it correctly.

`func(*str);` first decays the array to a pointer to the 1st element, and then deferences that pointer, thus passing just the 1st character to `func()`.  But there is no `func(char)` function defined, so this is an error.

`func(&str);` takes the address of the array, thus passing a pointer to the array, not a reference to it.  But there is no `func(char(*)[len])` function defined, so this is also an error.

To pass `str` by reference, you need to simply pass `str` as-is without `*` or `&`:

`func(str);`

This is no different than passing a reference to a variable of any other type, eg:

```
void func(int &value);

int i;
func(i);
```

---

On a side note: `printf(str);` is dangerous, since you don't know if `str` contains any `%` characters in it. A safer call would be either:

`printf("%s", str);`

Or:

`puts(str);`

But those only work if `str` is null-terminated (which it is in your case). Even safer would be:

`printf("%.s", (int)len, str);`

Which doesn't require a null terminator.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens with the precision-specified case for `%.s` when the length provided includes the full string *and* the terminator (as it does in the OPs code)? Does it stop at the encounter of the terminator, though included in `len`, or does it try to shove the terminator into the output stream as well? Just curious (and yes, a bit lazy; could prolly look i up myself; sry).

Comment: @WhozCraig The precision element of `%s` specifies a *maximum* length. `printf()` will print UP TO the specified max length, but *should* stop early if `'\0'` is encountered first.

Comment: That's my learned-something-new for today. Thanks, Remy.

Comment: Ok thanks.  That makes sense.  my misunderstanding ultimately was due to conflating the words "reference" and "pointer".  Could you elaborate a bit on how those terms are different in c++?

Comment: @Mr.Weathers [Already discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in).

Comment: @WhozCraig  Thanks for clarifying.  The overloading of the `&` symbol seems like a confusing choice

Comment: @Mr.Weathers When adding new features, the C++ committee likes to reuse symbols and keywords whenever possible. This avoids having to reserve new symbols and keywords, which may break compatibility with existing code.